# Array of properties in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, properties, excel

I have 13 properties following similar syntax as the one below:

```
Public Property Get Town() As String
    Town = txtTown.Text
End Property
```

I would like to be able to use a loop and iterate through a collection of these properties instead of referencing each of the 13 properties. How would I go about creating an array of these prexisting properties. I would very much prefer for them to keep their meaningful names.

**EDIT:**

```
aSet IDCell = customerDBSheet.Range("CustomerDBEntryPoint").Offset(ID() - 1)
Dim properties()
properties = Array("ID()", "FirstName()", "LastName()", "Address 1()", "Address 2()",     "Town()", "Postcode()", "Phone()", "Email()", "Sex()", "Username()", "PasswordHash()")
For i = 0 To 11
IDCell.Offset(1, i).Value = CStr(CallByName(frmCustomerEntry, properties(i), VbLet, ""))
Next i
```

I get an error on the line before last: `IDCell.Offset(1, i).Value = CStr(CallByName(frmCustomerEntry, properties(i), VbLet, ""))`

**Final Code:**

```
Dim properties()
properties = Array("ID", "FirstName", "LastName", "Address1", "Address2", "Town", "Postcode", "Phone", "Email", "Sex", "Username", "PasswordHash")
For i = 0 To 11
IDCell.Offset(1, i).Value = CStr(CallByName(frmCustomerEntry, properties(i), VbMethod))
Next i
```

The code used in the end, shown above specifically uses the CallByName function edited from Radek's answer as the property was converted to a function. Furthermore, the For loop needed to use a 0-based index. Also, an exception was thrown when the 4th optional parameter was an empty string literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through array of property names:

```
Dim vProperties()
Dim vPropertyName

vProperties = Array("Town", "Street", "ZipCode")
For Each vPropertyName In vProperties
    '''Do something
Next
```

Now is the "tricky" part: "Do something" block have only vPropertyName set to consecutive property names. In order to access property value by its name from string variable use CallByName function:

```
...
For Each vPropertyName In vProperties
    CallByName MyObject1, vPropertyName, VbLet, "" 
Next
```

The second option iteration through "Controls" collection of UserForm:

```
Dim vControl As Control

For Each vControl In UserForm1.Controls
    If TypeName(vControl) = "TextBox" OR vControl.Name Like "MyPattern*" Then
        '''Do something
    End If
Next
```

EDIT:

```
Dim properties()
properties = Array("ID", "FirstName", "LastName", "Address1", "Address2", "Town", "Postcode", "Phone", "Email", "Sex", "Username", "PasswordHash")
For i = LBound(properties) To UBound(properties)
    IDCell.Offset(1, i).Value = CStr(CallByName(frmCustomerEntry, properties(i), VbLet, ""))
Next i
```

I found few things in your code

- Parentheses are unnecessary
- Something is wrong witch properties "Address 1" and "Address 2". You can't define property with space inside the name
- I believe that the LBound and UBound functions are little bit more handy than using explicit boundaries of array

Comment: What does the MyObject1 refer to?

Comment: MyObject1 is reference to instance of the class where 13 properties are implemented

Comment: OK Thanks so it would be frmCustomerForm in this instance?

Comment: VBA dont clearly distinguish class and class instance for the Form objects/classes. But still CallByName for frmCustomerForm should works great.

Comment: "Run-time error '438':

Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: I added it to the question body

Comment: Never mind, it's a problem with VBA: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823604 - I'm just going to do it the long way

Comment: I also added comments to the answer body.

Comment: Yeah you're right, however it breaks before it gets to address1 & 2 and I am using explicit boundaries because I need to offset the cell and subtracting one reduces readability

Comment: Finally got it working :D The problem lay with my array indices - I assumed the array was 0-indexed like many programming langauges so I initialised it as `Dim properties(0 To 11)`